# sql query hangs/times out when passed large data

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

UPDATED:
Guys I am passing list of faculty id's to stored procedure, when i pass more than 10 faculty id's it's taking long time to process the data and sometime times out. I spent good amount of time on debugging this query and find out the last line in proc is causing query to timeout/slow response time. The last line is subquering from CTE. How to I rewrite/optimize last line of the proc to make my query run faster. Any help will be highly appreciated. Can someone help on this please.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_Test(
facultycode IN  varchar2
//few more variables
---
---
p_result OUT sys_refcursor
)
AS
open recordset for 
//this parses list of id's i.e('101''102''104'108') and i am calling this in last line of my proc
with faculty_list as (
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(facultycode,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) AS FAC_CODE
         FROM DUAL              
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE(facultycode,'[^,]+'))+1
    )

select s.s_name, m.score, s.status
 from student s 
join marks m on s.s_id = m.s_id 
WHERE S.GRADE>5
AND facultycode is null or s.fac_code in (select FAC_CODE from faculty_list); //this line 
is making query very slow, I need to optimize this line for faster response
END sp_Test;
```

Comment: first of all your query is wrong.

Comment: Could you please update you question with what you are trying to accomplish?  @BarbarosÖzhan is right, there are some issues with your query: Your PIVOT is unnecessary and unused.  You aren't selecting into anything.  Is your parameter being used or are you just using the phonenumber column from employee.  While not required, it helps to follow a standard when naming variables/parameters.

Comment: @Del this query is for test only, my query i very long and has similar structure. Trying to find out efficient way to process large data. I am passing list of phone numbers as a string and if I pass more than 10 phone numbers then query is taking 2 mins to output the result

Comment: Do you have to pass it as a string?  Could you pass it as a nested table or  associative array?  If so, you could join it into your query using the TABLE operator.

Comment: The question title is "Optimizing stored procedure" but in the text you ask how to how to "optimize my query". The sample procedure code is invalid, so I am not sure what the actual problem is.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I have updated my question, can you please have a look at it.

Comment: I think using CTE will slow your query , you might have to use different techniques to improve performance of your query. I am not expert in oracle , hopefully some experts can provide you better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the /*+ MATERIALIZE */ hint on the faculty_list with clause sub query.  In general, I'd say the performance would mostly depend on if student.faculty_code is indexed, you can add to this index the grade

```
create index student_fac_grade_idx on student (fac_code, grade);
```

If you have this index and the materialize hing, then you have the optimal chance of this performing well. The following works for null input list as well:

```
with in_list as
(
select '101,102,104,108,201,202,204,208,301,402,504,608' in_list from dual
--select '' in_list from dual
)
, faculty_list as 
(
SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ REGEXP_SUBSTR(in_list,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) AS FAC_CODE
         FROM DUAL , in_list    
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE(in_list,'[^,]+'))+1
)
--select * from faculty_list ;
, student as
(
select 1 s_id, 'Joe' s_name, 'ACTIVE' status , 6 grade, 101 fac_code from dual
)
, marks as
(
select 1 s_id, 100 score from dual
)
/* main query */
select s.s_name, m.score, s.status
from student s 
join marks m on s.s_id = m.s_id 
WHERE S.GRADE>5
and (s.fac_code in (select FAC_CODE from faculty_list)
or (select fac_code from faculty_list ) is null)
;
```

Comment: Roger thanks your effort, faculty_code is not indexed and I do not have permission to create index in a table but will try your solution and see If i get better performance. Thanks again

Comment: @user10806781 You can try to create it as a virtual index by adding the "NOSEGMENT" clause to the index create statement.  Then Alter your session to use the virtual index [ALTER SESSION SET "_use_nosegment_indexes" = TRUE;].  Then you can check the execution plan to see if it picks up the index or just re-run the query to see if it went faster.  Don't forget to drop the virtual index when done :).

Comment: @user10806781 To troubleshoot, I would decompose the parts into individual select statements to see what they are producing.  The where clause/join condition is essentially a logical expression that evaluates to true to get the final result set.  If your result set is off based on your manual evaluation, then the logical expression needs to be corrected.  Without your data set, it would be impossible for me to tell further from this "distance".

Comment: everything is working perfect, thank you very much for such a great help.Without you this solution was not possible. Thank you very much sir, have a blessed day.

Comment: My Pleasure. you too @user10806781 .